# How many 5 letters/number combinations?

Tags: combinations

How many combinations that are 5 characters can be made with numbers 0-9 and letters A-Z and all caps (e.g. ASX51)?

Comment: Do you allow repetition ? Do you take the order into account ?

Comment: Im not really sure what you mean but @marya answered

Comment: I meant that "combination" is not so clear : is $AAAAA$ a valid combination, or must the characters be all different ? Also, is $ASX51$ the same combination as $SAX51$ (because it has the same characters), or is it a different one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $26$ characters in the alphabet, and there are $10$ in $0$-$9$. So we have $36$ characters overall.

Therefore, there are
$$
\binom{36}{5}=\frac{36!}{(36-5)!5!}=\frac{36!}{31!5!}=\frac{36\cdot 35\cdot 34\cdot 33\cdot 32}{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}=3\cdot7\cdot 17\cdot 33\cdot 32=376,992
$$
different $5$ characters.

Comment: @AhmedEddine If the order of the characters is important, the answer changes to $$5! \times \binom{36}{5}.$$ If (in contrast) repetition is allowed (e.g. "AAA1X") then the answer changes to $$(36)^5.$$